# Include php configurations in multiple files

Tags: php

I have some configurations I need to apply to my php files, for example:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', false);
header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate");
```

But I have multiple files, ex.: user.php, blog.php, account.php, etc... So for each one of these files, I'm including that config code before the functions.

I'd like to know if there is an easier way to do it. I tried to create a new file (head.php) and include it using `include` or `require_once` but none of the seems to be working.

***user.php***

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__."/head.php";
// or
include "head.php";

function getUser() {
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't work. If I insert something in the database using the include/require code, the timezone is not correct, and when I have the code manually defined on the file, then the timezone is correct.

Same thing happens for errors, headers, etc...

Comment: Is your `head.php` file in the same dir as the other files?

Comment: do you mean mysql timezone? if so, then you need use mysql query to change database zone.

Comment: Questions that ask "Why isn't this code working" need to provide enough information that we can solve the issue.  We don't know what your directories look like.  This could be a path problem.

Comment: @Jite Yes, the path is correct.

Comment: check the output of get_included_files()

Comment: you told about database, so use `mysqli_query("SET time_zone='UTC'");` - to change MYSQL timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the PHP configuration file, that's the way to go. First find out [exactly which file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) PHP reads its configuration from:

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file(); // eg: /path/to/php.ini
```

Next, edit that **php.ini** file and set the [auto prepend directive](https://websistent.com/php-auto_prepend_file-and-auto_append_file/):

```
auto_prepend_file = /path/to/your/init.php
```

Next, create **init.php** and include all your global configuration code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Finally, restart the server. The auto prepend file is executed first, every time.

Comment: For some reason this is working now. I didn't changed much, but after following your steps it's working now.